# Regex to match domain ( CTLD Loop )

Tags: python, regex

So I am working on a small web scraper which Checks if target domain exists on the website.

This is my current code

```
target = "google.com"
pattern = r"(http|https):\/\/(www.|)"+re.escape(target)
patter = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
```

This regex pattern works fine till there is no CTLD domain present on the external page where the pattern is being used to find a match.

Test Case #1

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google.com</a>
Match Found
```

Test Case #2

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/bla-bla-article">Random.co</a>
Match Found
```

Test Case #3

This shouldn't happen. It shouldn't find a match since .com and .com.au aren't the same thing.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com.au">Google.com.au</a>
Match Found
```

Comment: `(www.|)`  -> `(?:www.)?`

Comment: `(http|https):\/\/` -> `https?:\/\/`

Comment: The programming language in use would be good to know.

Comment: I think Python, because `re.compile` and `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: Python as Ubombi mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, regex match everithing that starts like url with defined domain,

- **https://** **google.com**/q=somesearch
- **https://** **www.google.com**/someurl
- **https://** **www.google.com**.au/ etc...

So, you need to define limit of domain in that url.
*[protocol][address]**[port][path]**[query][hash]*
path starts with `/`, port with `:`

`https?:\/\/(:?www\.)?` + re.escape(target) + `/`

or even something like:
`https?:\/\/(:?www\.)?` + re.escape(target) + `(?:\:\d+)/`
If you wanna match `https://google.com:1488/somehiddenservice.json`

[**Regexp info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - all you ever need to know about regex

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Just noticed a bug. Adding a forward slash makes the regex not match a standalone domain URL. 
https://www.google.com/ ( Matched )
https://www.google.com ( Doesn't get matched

I tried adding `(\/?[^\.])` in the end but it doesn't seem to work in Python for some reason.

Comment: Yep, i see the problem... You should understand regex, before use it. 
Please read few pages from regex info. I promise, you will fix this regexp easily

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making this regex `($|[^.])`. Seems to work fine :D